# How do I calculate the induced metric in the Gibbons–Hawking–York boundary term?

Tags: general-relativity, boundary-terms

This question concerns the expression for the induced metric in the explicit variation of the [GHY boundary term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbons%E2%80%93Hawking%E2%80%93York_boundary_term). Just how is that expression derived in detail from the definition of the induced metric in this case? The expression is h = g - nn where indices have been left off.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty close to a previously-asked question. You can see my answer here: [Explicit Variation of Gibbons-Hawking-York Boundary Term](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10606/explicit-variation-of-gibbons-hawking-york-boundary-term/10628#10628)