# Gibbons-Hawking Variation

Tags: general-relativity, variational-principle, action, variational-calculus, boundary-terms

I know there already exist some questions about this and some very good answers. However, I am still having trouble understanding one part of the calculation. The GHY term is given by

$S_{GHY}=-\frac{1}{8 \pi G} \int_{\partial M} d^dx \sqrt{-h} K$

I'm really confused about how to compute $\delta K$:

1, I would have thought $K$ as the trace of the extrinsic curvature $K^{\mu \nu}=-\frac{1}{2} (\nabla^\mu n^\nu + \nabla^\nu n^\mu)$ would be given by $K=K^{\mu \nu} g_{\mu \nu}$. I believe I'm supposed to contract with $g_{\mu \nu}$ rather than $h_{\mu \nu}$ since the normal vector is not confined to $\partial M$ - can someone confirm this please?

2, If I then vary $K$ I find $\delta K =  K^{\mu \nu} \delta g_{\mu \nu} + \delta K^{\mu \nu} g_{\mu \nu}$ but according to [Explicit Variation of Gibbons-Hawking-York Boundary Term](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10606/explicit-variation-of-gibbons-hawking-york-boundary-term), I should have $-\frac{1}{2} K^{\mu \nu} \delta g_{\mu \nu}$ on the first term. It appears I'm out by a minus sign and a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ but I don't know why though?

3, We have $\delta K = \dots + g_{\mu \nu} \delta K^{\mu \nu}$ and I don't know how he gets this expression for the variation. Could somebody please explain how he does the variation of the normal vector and picks up this conrtibution $c_\mu$. N.B. I tried to follow the advice in one of the comments to consider a specific example of $n_\mu$ but I couldn't find the correct variation of $\alpha_\mu$?

Thanks.

Comment: This calculation is done in e.g. Wald's GR book. (Appendix E.)

Comment: @0celo7 hmmm. I understand the point of introducing the GHY term is to cancel the boundary contribution from the EH term. However, we now seem to have introduced a $\int_{\partial M} \sqrt{-h} \frac{1}{2}( h^{\mu \nu} K-K^{\mu \nu} ) \delta g_{\mu \nu}$ contribution. Why doesn't this affect the EoMs?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10606/

Comment: @0celo7 yeah this is the one I link to in my original post. Do you understand how he varies the normal vector?

Comment: Whoops, sorry the link was darkened because I had already clicked on it. I didn't see it in your post. I'll read it and give it some though.