# Variation of normal, coordinate and mean curvature with respect to metric

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, variational-calculus

Using the divergence theorem, we can compute volume by integrating along the surface:
$$\mathrm{vol}(M)=\int_M\mathrm{d}V=\oint_{\partial M}\mathrm{d}S \,\vec{n}\cdot\vec{v},$$
where $\vec{n}$ is normal to $\partial M$ and $\vec{v}$ is a vector fulfilling $\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{v}=1$, e.g. $\vec{v}=x\hat{e_x}$. Bringing it into the from
$$\mathrm{vol}(M)=\oint_{\partial M}\mathrm{d}^{d-1}x\,n_\alpha x^\alpha\sqrt{g},$$
where now $g$ is the determinant of the metric tensor and $n_\alpha$ the normal to $\partial M$, I wanted to compute the variation of this integral w.r.t. the metric $g_{ij}$:
$$\oint_{\partial M}\mathrm{d}^{d-1}x\,\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\frac{\delta(n_\alpha x^\alpha\sqrt{g})}{\delta g^{ij}}\right)\sqrt{g}.$$
Using the product rule, this boils down in computing the first term in
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\frac{\delta(n_\alpha x^\alpha\sqrt{g})}{\delta g^{ij}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\frac{\delta(n_\alpha x^\alpha)}{\delta g^{ij}}-\frac{n_\alpha x^\alpha}{2}g_{ij},$$
but I'm not sure how to do it. $x^\alpha$ are components of the parametrization of $\partial M$.

**Edit:** In this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10606/explicit-variation-of-gibbons-hawking-york-boundary-term) the functional derivative of $n_\alpha$ is given as (after lowering/raising indices)
$$\frac{\delta n_\alpha}{\delta g^{ij}}=-\frac{1}{2}n_\alpha n_in_j$$
but no derivation is stated nor where to look it up. The only other quantity missing then is
$$\frac{\delta x^\alpha}{\delta g^{ij}}=?$$

**Edit 2:** As a follow up question, what is the functional derivative of the mean curvature
$$H=-\frac{1}{2}\nabla_\alpha n^\alpha$$
w.r.t. the metric, i.e.
$$\frac{\delta H}{\delta g^{ij}}=?.$$
This is related to the derivative of the normal, as we have
$$H=-\frac{1}{2}\nabla_\alpha n^\alpha=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{g}}\frac{\partial(\sqrt{g}n^\alpha)}{\partial x^\alpha}$$
and thus
$$\frac{\delta H}{\delta g^{ij}}=\frac{H}{4}g_{ij}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{g}}\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{ij}}\left(\frac{\partial(\sqrt{g}n^\alpha)}{\partial x^\alpha}\right),$$
but I'm not sure what to do about the last term.

Comment: People usually choose $\vec v=\frac{1}{3}x^i\vec e_i$ (see it as the volume of  a pyramid and restores the symmetry in the variables). To answer your question, you’ll need to be more precise. Does the variation of $g$ is like in GR and « localized » on the surface, or is it due to a constant ambient $g$ defined in $ \mathbb R^3$ and its variation on the surface is due to the displacement of the surface.

Comment: The metric is defined by the parametrization of the surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, e.g. the surface of a sphere has $g=\begin{pmatrix}r^2&0\\0&r^2\sin^2(\theta)\end{pmatrix}$. Essentially you have some parametrized surface $\vec{S}(u,v)=(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$